# Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'Particle Emitter.emit' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'Particle Emitter.emit' cannot be used like a method (27)
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'UnityEngine.Particle[]' (28)
Are my error code. I have been working on this code for a while now I made it exactly how I was told to and it keeps having problems. I am trying to look but can't find what is wrong with it.
Here is my script:

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LightningBolt : MonoBehaviour
{
 public Transform target;
 public int zigs = 100;
 public float speed = 1f;
 public float scale = 1f;
 public Light endLight;
 [HideInInspector] public bool emits = false;
 
 Perlin noise;
 float oneOverZigs;
 
 private Particle[] particles;
 
 void Start()
 {
  oneOverZigs = 1f / (float)zigs;
        GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().emit = false;

        GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().emit(zigs);
  particles = GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().emit;
 }
 
 void Update ()
 {
  if(target == null)
   return;
  if(!emits){
   return;
  }
  endLight.intensity = 1;
  if (noise == null)
   noise = new Perlin();
   
  float timex = Time.time * speed * 0.1365143f;
  float timey = Time.time * speed * 1.21688f;
  float timez = Time.time * speed * 2.5564f;
  
  for (int i=0; i < particles.Length; i++)
  {
   Vector3 position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, oneOverZigs * (float)i);
   Vector3 offset = new Vector3(noise.Noise(timex + position.x, timex + position.y, timex + position.z),
          noise.Noise(timey + position.x, timey + position.y, timey + position.z),
          noise.Noise(timez + position.x, timez + position.y, timez + position.z));
   position += (offset * scale * ((float)i * oneOverZigs));
   
   particles[i].position = position;
   particles[i].color = Color.white;
   particles[i].energy = 1f;
  }

        GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().particles = particles;
  
  if (GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().particleCount >= 2)
  {
   if (endLight)
    endLight.transform.position = particles[particles.Length - 1].position;
  }
 } 
 
 void EmitCharge (bool s) {
  emits = s;
  endLight.intensity = 0;
 }
 
 /* C
  */
 void Target (Transform t) {
  target = t;
 }
}
```

Comment: You do `emit = false` and `emit(zigs)`.  It cannot be a `bool` and a method.

Answer (score 0):

Particles is an array of particles (that means that more than one particles are inside it). You can't use a single particle method on an array of them unless you iterate them (a for loop for example)
EDIT: looking the code in more detail i'm not really sure what you want to do with that particle array. If you want to store a reference to the emit bool, you should store it in a bool, not in a particles array (could be something like bool particleState = getcomponent().emit). If you do this declare particleState before the start method so you can access this variable in your update method as well.